# Error deserialize JSON - Como Resolver?

Tags: java, jpa, rest

Estou usando jpa e tenho essas duas entidades:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id")

public class Categoria implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private int id;
    private String tipo;

    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoria_id")
    private List<Post> categoria_post;
}


    @Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
  property = "id")
public class Post implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotNull
    private String titulo;
    @NotNull
    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToOne
    private Categoria categoria_id;
    @NotNull
    private String descricao;
    private String img;
    @ManyToOne
    private Usuario post_usuario;
    private int likes;
}
```

Quando faço um post para persistir um um objeto no banco, recebo essa exceção:
[image: error postman]

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.
root cause

javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.
root cause

javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Error deserialize JSON value into type: class com.emerich.model.Categoria.

Comment: Tem como por o texto do erro? Fica melhor para ler, talvez até mesmo para copiar o texto para uma resposta

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.

javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Error deserialize JSON value into type: class com.emerich.model.Categoria.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia.
O problema foi solucionado, a estrutura do meu JSON estava incorreta:

Correto:

```
{
        "titulo": "Combatendo a Fome",
        "categoria_id": {"id":"1"},
        "descricao": "Projeto Destinado a distribuição cestas básicas..",
        "img": "fome.png",
        "post_usuario": {"id":"1"},
        "likes": 12

    }
```

Incorreto:

```
{
    "titulo": "Combatendo a Fome",
    "categoria_id": 1,
    "descricao": "Projeto Destinado a distribuição cestas básicas..",
    "img": "fome.png",
    "post_usuario": 1,
    "likes": 12

}
```

Isso por que as minhas entidades possuem relacionamento ManyToOne e OneToMany do jpa e minha api não estava tratando a deserialiazação desses objetos. Aproveitando a solução, existe alguma forma de tratar isso automaticamente na api?